# add-migration push visual studion in 'Microsoft visual studio is busy'

Tags: entity-framework, migration, nuget, entity-framework-migrations

I tried to use ado.net migrations and when type add-migration in nu-get console i sometimes(in 50% of cases) cause visual studio in stuck and get the mesage  Microsoft visual studio is busy.

Version of nu-get is 1.5.2
Migrations version 0.7

Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: Sometimes the  migration takes a while. If you wait long enough, does it come back?